# Jetty server 7.6.9 loosing cookie in AJAX and high concurrency situation

Tags: session, cookies, jetty, session-cookies

I have a page which will send some ajax request to my Jetty7.6.9 server. All of them containing a COOKIE named JSESSIONID so that the server knows the request is logged in.

But sometimes, the method `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getCookies()` returns an empty `Cookie[]`. I set a breakpoint and checked the `_connection._requestFields` and I found the Cookie right there, but `Request.getCookies()` cannot fetch it or parse it.

The situation can happen in any one or more ajax request in that page, can happen in any time, can happen in both windows and linux. It seems that it's a random case, and even when I dropped the frame at the breakpoint to the pre line, it would run correctly when it ran to the same place, so I think it's an issue about synchronize/concurrent.

I didn't find the same case in jetty bug list.

Is it a bug? What can I do to verify or repeat it? How to fix it?

(For some reason,maybe I cannot update the Jetty version for our system.)